# Existence of a class of graphs with a special property

Tags: graph-theory

In the following, suppose all graphs are simple and finite. For a given graph $G$, we denote its complement by $\overline{G}$. Let $*$ be a binary operation on graphs, such as Cartesian product, Kronecker product or etc. I am looking for to study the graphs which have the below property:$$\overline{G*H}\cong \overline{G}*H.$$

It seems that such a graphs are so rare. Are there an infinite family of graphs with the above property? Also, if there are some good reference for these type of problems, I appreciate if you mention them.

$\textbf{Added Later (11/11/2017)}:$
As an example that such graphs exist, but a rather trivial example, we can take $H$ to be a one-vertex graph, and an arbitrary graph $G$. For example, let the binary operation $*={\scriptsize\boxtimes}$ be the  [strong product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_product_of_graphs). Therefore, $\overline{G\ {\scriptsize\boxtimes}\ H}\cong \overline{G}\cong \overline{G}\ {\scriptsize\boxtimes}\ H$.

However, I am interested in the cases where none of the graphs $G$ and $H$ are edgeless.

Comment: Dear @Sharooz Janbaz: several edits to this post were made: if you object, feel free to re-edit; it seems to me that all are improvements; in particular, I would strongly recommend not writing $\{v\}$ for a one-vertex graph, and not calling the one-vertex graph 'empty'; on a mathematical note: what makes you assume that the graphs be "finite"?

Comment: Dear @Peter Heinig, Thanks for your edits. Actually, your edits improved the style of this question. I am working on the spectrum of finite graphs, so the above equation is written down for finite graphs. But, maybe the infinite case be interesting in its own personality.